# Deployment error on Azure with Bitbucket (ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Bad file number)

Tags: php, mysql, azure, ssh, bitbucket

I have a setup on Azure Websites where my Bitbucket repository is connected to my deployment slot. I can get it to work, but then every now and then (2 days) I get this error "ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Bad file number". Following this, all my websites (also ones not showing this error) lose connection to my databases and can't run. For this specific website I can't get it to access Bitbucket again (solved once by deleting source code with FTP).

Can anyone lead me in the direction of a solution?

Note: Also other websites lose connection and I can't make sense of this. Why would these be affected. Database is still running. I'm not sure whether there could be another error that makes the site lose connections.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you have some configurations on your web site? As I just test to deploy from Bitbucket several times, it worked fine for me. Could you create a new Web Apps and try to deploy from your bitbucket repository again? Will it reproduce your issue?

Comment: I removed the connection to Bitbucket last night (where it didn't go through immediately) and this morning, when I connect, it deploys again. This unfortunalely is not the solution, since I did this before. It's only a matter of time before it happens again. When it runs, it runs fine. I have configuration in the Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry that I post the comment as an answer post here due to comment's characters limited*

@nicolaib, since the issue (error "ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Bad file number".) is a bit hard to reproduce on our side, could you please share the web app's info with us via leveraging the approach that pointed out at https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly? The basic idea is - if you prefer not to share the info publicly on the forum (which we fully understand), there is an alternate way that will allow us to know your site name without revealing it to others, even if you cannot create a site, you can find the info sharing approach at the bottom of https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly. Should you have any further concern, please feel free to let us know. Looking forward to having your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issue today (deployment failure due to "ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Bad file number"). Resyncing from the new Azure Portal lead to the same error, but when I resynced using the old Azure Mgmt Portal - deployment succeeded.